# SF Symbol Tint Color Not Working For Cosmos View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, sf-symbols

I am using Cosmos View to show an array of 'stars' [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Cosmos)

I have set up the view in my cell and I would like to use SF Symbols for the star image. However, the tint colour isn't working here's my code below, I don't know if I'm missing anything?

```
private let starView: CosmosView = {
    let view = CosmosView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    view.settings.starSize = 16
    view.settings.starMargin = 2
    view.settings.disablePanGestures = true
    view.settings.updateOnTouch = false
    view.settings.filledImage = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill")?.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    view.settings.emptyImage = UIImage(systemName: "star")?.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    view.settings.fillMode = .half
    return view
}()
```

With this, it is still giving me the default colour. not `.red` as specified as the tint colour.